# Customize pipelines list when a pipeline is scheduled multiple times a day, more frequently than the code changes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to run a GitLab pipeline at four specific times each day, which I have solved by setting up four schedules, one for each desired point in time. All pipelines run on the same branch, `master`.

In the list of pipelines, I get the following information for each pipeline:

- status (success or not)
- pipeline ID, a label indicating the pipeline was triggered by a schedule, and a label indicating the pipeline was run on the latest commit on that branch
- the user that triggered the pipeline
- branch and commit on which the pipeline was run
- status (success, warning, failure) for each stage
- duration and time at which the pipeline was run (X hours/days/... ago)

This seems optimized to pipelines which typically run no more than once after each commit: in such a scenario, it is relatively easy to identify a particular pipeline.

In my case, however, the code itself has relatively little changes (the main purpose of the pipeline is to verify against external data which changes several times a day). As a result, I end up with a list of near-identical entries. In fact, the only difference is the time at which the pipeline was run, though for anything older than 24 hours I will get 4 pipelines that ran “2 days ago”.

Is there any way I can customize these entries? For a scheduled pipeline, I would like to have an indicator of the schedule which triggered the pipeline or the time of day (even for pipelines older than 24 hours), optionally a date (e.g. “August 16” rather than “5 days ago”).

Comment: I'm not aware of anything, but that would be a good feature request to file.

Comment: Done, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/339060

Answer (score 2):

To enable the use of absolute times in GitLab:

1. Click your Avatar in the top right corner.
2. Click `Preferences`.
3. Scroll to `Time preferences` and uncheck the box next to `Use relative times.`

Your pipelines will now show the actual date and time at which they were triggered rather than a relative time.

More info here: https://gitlab.com/help/user/profile/preferences#time-preferences